# Any way to merge tifs with overviewsm or overvies alone

Tags: gdal, merge, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt, map-overviews

I have a large dataset of tif images with external overviews. Is there any way to merge these images to one bigtiff including the overviews? Using vrt and gdal_translate doesn't seem to be working. Cannot build vrt on the ovr files alone, since they are not georeferenced and gdal_merge.py doesn't work either.

I'd rather not build the overviews again, since that's going to be extremely time consuming (weeks likely).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the target format that should be possible. See https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html.

> COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=[YES/NO]: (CreateCopy() only) By setting this to
> YES (default is NO), the potential existing overviews of the source
> dataset will be copied to the target dataset without being recomputed.
> This option is typically used to generate Cloud Optimized Geotiff
> (starting with GDAL 3.1, the COG – Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF generator
> driver can be used as a convenient shortcut). If overviews of mask
> band also exist, provided that the GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK
> configuration option is set to YES, they will also be copied. Note
> that this creation option will have no effect if general options (i.e.
> options which are not creation options) of gdal_translate are used.
> Creation options related to compression are also applied to the output
> overviews.

Notice that this option is a driver specific creation option `-co` and therefore it is not documented in the gdal_translate documentation.

I would try first simply

- to build a vrt from tifs with gdalbuildvrt
- to create a BigTIFF or COG with gdal_translate by using option `-co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES`

However, merging gives indeed extra challenges. If gdal_translate does not work directly then your plan to build a vrt from ovr files might work but it would require a few more steps. Overviews are indirectly georeferenced because they steal the georeferencing from the main image. You could perhaps write a script that reads the georeferencing of the main images and writes the info permanently into for example PAM files (.aux.xml) so it could be utilized for the .ovr files.

Comment: I tested using vrt + gdal_translate with COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES, but no luck. It seems that the option is not used when dealing with vrt's. Seems like I have to make my own version of gdal_merge.py, that can merge ovr files also.

Comment: Or it may be that GDAL thinks that the vrt combined from images with overviews does not  have overviews itself. Does `gdalinfo your.vrt` list overviews?

Comment: It does not. Considering that vrt is not a "real" image file I have assumed that gdalinfo would work in non-standard way, and the actual overviews would be used by the application reading the vrt file (qgis, geoserver, depending if the app supports them).

Comment: Right, I suppose that individual overviews work transparently if you open the big vrt with a client like QGIS. The problem is in how to make the 5000 ovr files to work together as one overview for the one merged BigTIFF.